# How check what lines are equal in two text files?

Tags: delphi, string-comparison, delphi-10.3-rio

This simply code is working fine to check if lines are different, already when i try check if are equals none element is found when have two files with the same string in same line index on both. What is missing here?

**PS:** [`SameStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.SameStr) also was tested and not is working.

```
function compstr(s1, s2: string): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
  btemp: boolean;
begin
  btemp := true;
  if (length(s1) <> length(s2)) then
  begin
    btemp := false;
  end
  else
  begin
    for i := 1 to length(s1) do
    begin
      if (s1[i] <> s2[i]) then
      begin
        btemp := false;
        exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  result := btemp;
end;

procedure compfile(filename1, filename2: string);
var
  f1: system.textfile;
  f2: system.textfile;
  diff: system.textfile;
  buf1: string;
  buf2: string;
  l: integer;
begin
  assignfile(f1, filename1);
  assignfile(f2, filename2);
  assignfile(diff, 'C:\Equals.txt');
  reset(f1);
  reset(f2);
  rewrite(diff);
  l := 1;
  while not eof(f1) do
  begin
    readln(f1, buf1);
    readln(f2, buf2);
    if {not} compstr(buf1, buf2) then
    begin
      writeln(diff, {extractfilename(filename1) + ' : ' +} inttostr(l) + ' - ' + buf1);
     // writeln(diff, extractfilename(filename2) + ' : ' + inttostr(l) + ' - ' + buf2);
     // writeln(diff, ' ');
    end;
    inc(l);
  end;
  closefile(f1);
  closefile(f2);
  closefile(diff);
end;
```

Comment: The piece of code with `exit;` gives unknown function return value because `Result` is not assigned

Comment: I think the "Exit" line in compstr happens before you ever set a result value.  I'd think that would cause a compiler hint or warning.

Comment: P.S. SameStr and a lot of other string comparison functions including `if s1 = s2` do work.

Comment: @MBo, after more some tests i discovered that comparation to verify equality is working, but only if all lines are equals on both files, if have at least one element different in any file the code fail.

Comment: `Exit` exits the current **function / procedure** immediately. Maybe you were thinking to use `Break` which exits a currently running `For`, `While` or `Repeat` loop.

Comment: @Davison Yes, but comparison of files for equality assumes that all lines are equal. If you need another result  - specify problem accurately and implement corresponding logic. Perhaps you want some kind of `diff` - there are good implementations of `diff` algo [the first googled one](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/textdiff.html)

Comment: `[dcc64 Warning] W1035 Return value of function 'compstr' might be undefined`.  The lesson here is *don't ignore compiler warnings*.  They are there for a reason - to save you from yourself.  Take the time to read them and understand what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `function compstr(s1, s2: string): boolean;` has a couple of issues:

1. The `btemp: boolean` variable is unnecessary. You can set `result` directly as needed.
2. If the length of the two lines are equal, but the content differs (`if (s1[i] <> s2[i])`) you call `exit` which jumps to the `end;` of the function and `result` is never assigned the value of `btemp`. Thus, strings of equal length but different content are returning the value `True`, that you set at the beginning. Perhaps you were thinking about `break` which would exit the `for` loop and land on the `result := btemp;` line, which then would yield the correct value.
3. The whole function is a waste, you call it it in `compfile()` with:

```
   ...
   if compstr(buf1, buf2) then
   ....
```

which can be replaced with direct comparison:

```
   ....
   if buf1 = buf2 then
   ....
```

P.S. Your claim that `SameStr()` is not working is false. You probably did not use it correctly.

Comment: I wonder how long it'll be before we get "if not buf1 = buf2 is not working" ...;=)